# Retrieving the highest column value

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext

I have info in a database which can have different versions per entity. I want to retrieve the highest entity 
I want to get the highest version from the column Version. Now I'm doing this like this:

```
long version = DbContext.ElectronicSignatureTypes.Count(est => est.Entity.Name == entity);
```

but if a version would be removed the number wouldn't be equal. How can I get all the values from that one column over multiple results?

Comment: _highest entity_ ?! what is a high entity? how much high is he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Max maybe.

```
long version = DbContext.ElectronicSignatureTypes
                .Where(est => est.Entity.Name == entity)
                .Max(est => est.Version);
```